# Unable to get frequency values using ML5.js pitchdetection

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I'm using ML5.js with P5.js for Pitch Detection of musical instruments. when I allow microphone, I'm unable to detect the frequency ( getting null values ). The callback functions are working fine. the below is the following code I have written

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DSP Pitch detector!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- p5 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ml5 -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.0/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <p>this is detection</p>
    <script>
      // Your code will go here
      // open up your console - if everything loaded properly you should see 0.3.1

      const model_url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ml5js/ml5-data-and-models/models/pitch-detection/crepe/';
      let pitch;
      let audioContext;
      let mic;
      let freq = 0;


      console.log('ml5 version:', ml5.version);



      //p5.js
      function setup(){
        createCanvas(600, 600);
        audioContext = getAudioContext();
        mic = new p5.AudioIn();
        mic.start(listening);
      }

      //once listening modal is loaded
      //once modal is loaded we'll call get pitch and got pitch

      function listening() {
        console.log('listening!!');
        pitch = ml5.pitchDetection(
        model_url,
        audioContext,
        mic.stream,
        modelLoaded
        );
      }

      function modelLoaded() {
          console.log('modal loaded!!');
          pitch.getPitch(gotPitch);

      }

      function gotPitch(error, frequency){
          if(error){
              console.error(error)
          }
          else{
              if(frequency){
                  freq = frequency;
              }
            //   console.log(frequency);
          }
        // once you got the pitch and you loaded it ... you watch to decet the pitch again
        pitch.getPitch(gotPitch);
      }


      function draw(){
        background(200);
        textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
        fill(255);
        textSize(64);
        text(freq.toFixed(2), width/2,height/2)

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I should get frequency values when it hears audio, but I'm getting null values